# How to debug a 404 error in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I deployed a C# ASP.net project on IIS express server. When I use browser to access, localhost:8081/home/action, I got error below:

[image]

Here's something in the project.
Project structure:
[image]

related controller:

There's a HomeController.cs.

```
namespace ProjA.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Action()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to locate the 404.0 error, which indicate the url is not correct.

Comment: Lacks [mcve] if it's about your specific case. If it's about the general topic of debugging ASP.NET, that's too broad, L2G.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set in web.config

```
<trace enabled="true" />
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973.aspx)

Also you can try deploying the application in debug mode

Answer (score 2):

Because you have not assigned any explicit name in Controller action. So, make sure you have the Index and Action view in Home folder inside Views.

For enabling the trace: 
Turn Off Custom Error Messages

You will need to disable the friendly error page first by changing the customErrors mode to Off in web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Next, you will need to turn on debugging and trace.

```
<trace enabled="true" />
<compilation debug="true" >
```

Comment: Sorry I take mistakes editing your post:(